# Manipulating api response into a list of object key/value pairs

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Having trouble manipulating this data for my front end.

Here is my API response, which is a list of dictionaries:

```
    {
      "name": "bob",
      "age": 22,
      "gender": male
     },
      {
      "name": "zack",
      "age": 43,
      "gender": male
     }
```

Here is the desired output,  another list of dictionaries:

```
{id: 0, column: "age", bob: 22, zack: 43},
{id: 1, column: "gender", bob: male, zack: male}
```

So if another name was returned, it would simply be added as a key and grab the corresponding value for age/gender etc..

Here is the output I'm currently getting:

```
{id: 0, column: "age", bob: 22},
{id: 1, column: "gender", bob: male},

{id: 0, column: "age", zack: 43},
{id: 1, column: "gender", zack: male}
```

So for each list of dicts, I'm selecting the columns, using the name has a type of identifier, and assigning the corresponding value for a particular column.

I'm having trouble adding each person's name (the key in this case) to the same list of dicts with the corresponding value, age, gender, etc.. Here is the code I currently have.

```
my_list = []

counter = 0
for d in data:
    for k, v in d.items():
        dict = {}
        length = len(d.keys())
        if counter == length:
            counter = 0
        value = d['name']
        dict['id'] = counter
        dict['column'] = k
        dict[value] = v
        my_list.append(dict)
        counter += 1
```

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
data = [{
    "name": "bob",
    "age": 22,
    "gender": "male"
},
    {
        "name": "zack",
        "age": 43,
        "gender": "male"
    }]

keys = ["age", "gender"]

lookup = {key: {"id": i, "column" : key} for i, key in enumerate(keys)}

for d in data:
    name = d.pop("name")
    for key, value in d.items():
        lookup[key][name] = value

res = list(lookup.values())
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
[{'id': 0, 'column': 'age', 'bob': 22, 'zack': 43}, {'id': 1, 'column': 'gender', 'bob': 'male', 'zack': 'male'}]
```

Or an alternative that does not alter the original dictionary:

```
keys = ["age", "gender"]
lookup = {key: {"id": i, "column" : key} for i, key in enumerate(keys)}

for d in data:
    name = d["name"]
    for key in (d.keys() - {"name"}):
        lookup[key][name] = d[key]

res = list(lookup.values())
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
[{'id': 0, 'column': 'age', 'bob': 22, 'zack': 43}, {'id': 1, 'column': 'gender', 'bob': 'male', 'zack': 'male'}]
```

**UPDATE**

If the keys are not known before hand, you could do:

```
lookup = {}
for d in data:
    name = d["name"]
    for key in (d.keys() - {"name"}):
        if key not in lookup:
            lookup[key] = {key: {"id": len(lookup), "column": key}}
        lookup[key][name] = d[key]

res = list(lookup.values())
print(res)
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. In my scenario, I have over 300 key/values and they may change. The only key that I know that I'll have and that won't change is the key "name". So I can't hardcode the keys into a list. How would you go about that?

Comment: @kdrumz Added and update that may work

Comment: still isn't formatting quite how I need. Thanks for the help.